# Getting error at the time of Use-AzureSqlJobConnection -CurrentAzureSubscription

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-elasticpool

I am trying to execute the script on an elastic pool using powershell. When I execute this command,

Use-AzureSqlJobConnection -CurrentAzureSubscription -ResourceGroupName {ABC}

It is giving me error for, *Use-AzureSqlJobConnection : No Elastic Database Jobs control database found.*

Please help me with what I am missing here, to create something in the portal ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to execute a script on your databases using elastic jobs, you should first Create and configure the agent, the elastic database job agent (it is a service running on azure for automation on Azure SQL Databases).
in this case you should look into the links about it:

some overview about the service:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/elastic-jobs-overview

configure the servic jobs using Powershell:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/elastic-jobs-powershell

configure the servic jobs using TSQL:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/elastic-jobs-tsql

If you just want to to use Power Shell to run the same script on all of your databases (once), 
you may want to use another script dew to `-ResourceGroupName` is a property of Elastic jobs.
you should try using command like `Invoke-Sqlcmd`, iterating on all databases in the elastic pool.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps

I recommend you to try look into the Powershell Model `dbatools` (https://dbatools.io/) 
it has a lot of useful powershell commands ready to use.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the below document to install Elastic Database jobs and then you would be able to run `Use-AzureSqlJobConnection -CurrentAzureSubscription`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-jobs-service-installation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/elastic-jobs-overview

Thanks!